# Bootstrap drop down list items get cropped with Telerik popup window

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, telerik, telerik-window

I'm using telerik window to show popup. The popup window has bootstrap drop down list. When I click on drop down list, then dropdownlist items gets cropped behind the popup window.

I want the drop down list to be infront of the popup window. That is guess z-index needs to be greater than popup window. I tried setting z-index of drop downlist to higher but that did not work.

Here is the [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UPoFE/10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have to add this css :

```
  <style>
    div.k-window-content{overflow:visible;}   
  </style>
```

**Demo** : http://dojo.telerik.com/epIFa